# how can I make difference between two dates?

Tags: php, date

I have two dates. I want the following behavior:

> If today falls between the start and expiring dates, then *do something*.

But now both statements are true and I don't know why. The code looks good, but the 2 dates (`start_datemostfinishedweekly` and `start_dateplaytimeweekly`) are the same.

```
$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "2018-02-09 16:00:00";
$start_datemostfinishedweekly = date($timestampmostfinishedweekly);
$expiresmostfinishedweekly = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($timestampmostfinishedweekly));
$expiresmostfinishedweekly2 = strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($timestampmostfinishedweekly));

$timestampplaytimeweekly = "2018-02-02 16:00:00";
$start_dateplaytimeweekly = date($timestampplaytimeweekly);
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($timestampplaytimeweekly));
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly2 = strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($timestampplaytimeweekly));

// CHALLENGES
if(date('Y-m-d H:i') >= date('Y-m-d H:i', $start_datemostfinishedweekly) && date('Y-m-d H:i') <= date('Y-m-d H:i', $expiresmostfinishedweekly)){
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -0 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" text="Weekly Challenge:"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -2.5 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" textcolor="FF0" text="Reach the MOST Finish!"/>';
}
if(date('Y-m-d H:i') >= date('Y-m-d H:i', $start_dateplaytimeweekly) && date('Y-m-d H:i') <= date('Y-m-d H:i', $expireshetiplaytimeweekly)){
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -0 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" text="Weekly Challenge:"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -2.5 0.04" sizen="28 2" scale="0.8" textcolor="FF0" text="Drive the MOST time on the server!"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -5.1 0.04" sizen="32 2" textsize="0.8" text="***the time what you spend with driving are counted"/>';
    //$xml .= '<label posn="0 -5.8 0.04" sizen="32 2" textsize="0.8" text="***times are counted by Finish or when leave server"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got these errors when running your code:

```
[Sat Feb 03 14:21:29.504277 2018] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 14
[Sat Feb 03 14:21:29.504464 2018] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered on line 18
```

But this code is working perfectly:

```
<?php
$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "2018-02-09 16:00:00";
$start_datemostfinishedweekly = new DateTime($timestampmostfinishedweekly);
$expiresmostfinishedweekly = new DateTime($timestampmostfinishedweekly);
$expiresmostfinishedweekly2 = new DateTime($timestampmostfinishedweekly);
$expiresmostfinishedweekly->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$expiresmostfinishedweekly2->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));

$timestampplaytimeweekly = "2018-02-02 16:00:00";
$start_dateplaytimeweekly = new DateTime($timestampplaytimeweekly);
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly = new DateTime($timestampplaytimeweekly);
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly2 = new DateTime($timestampplaytimeweekly);
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly2->add(new DateInterval('P14D'));

$now = new DateTime('now');

// CHALLENGES
$xml = '';
if($now >= $start_datemostfinishedweekly && $now <= $expiresmostfinishedweekly){
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -0 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" text="Weekly Challenge:"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -2.5 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" textcolor="FF0" text="Reach the MOST Finish!"/>';
}
if($now >= $start_dateplaytimeweekly && $now <= $expireshetiplaytimeweekly){
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -0 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" text="Weekly Challenge:"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -2.5 0.04" sizen="28 2" scale="0.8" textcolor="FF0" text="Drive the MOST time on the server!"/>';
    $xml .= '<label posn="0 -5.1 0.04" sizen="32 2" textsize="0.8" text="***the time what you spend with driving are counted"/>';
    //$xml .= '<label posn="0 -5.8 0.04" sizen="32 2" textsize="0.8" text="***times are counted by Finish or when leave server"/>';
}

echo '<pre>'.$xml.'</pre>';
//echo '<xmp>'.$xml.'</xmp>'; <- this is the one working for me, but <pre> should do fine.
//echo '<code>'.$xml.'</code>';
?>
```

Let me also add the following code *for reference and debugging purposes*:

```
<?php
var_dump($now >= $start_datemostfinishedweekly);
var_dump($now <= $expiresmostfinishedweekly);
var_dump($now >= $start_dateplaytimeweekly);
var_dump($now <= $expireshetiplaytimeweekly);
echo 'Now: '.$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
echo '$start_datemostfinishedweekly: '.$start_datemostfinishedweekly->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
echo '$expiresmostfinishedweekly: '.$expiresmostfinishedweekly->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
echo '$start_dateplaytimeweekly: '.$start_dateplaytimeweekly->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
echo '$expireshetiplaytimeweekly: '.$expireshetiplaytimeweekly->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
?>
```

I got the following result:

```
<pre>
    <label posn="0 -0 0.04" sizen="24 2" scale="0.8" text="Weekly Challenge:">
        <label posn="0 -2.5 0.04" sizen="28 2" scale="0.8" textcolor="FF0" text="Drive the MOST time on the server!">
            <label posn="0 -5.1 0.04" sizen="32 2" textsize="0.8" text="***the time what you spend with driving are counted"></label>
        </label>
    </label>
</pre>
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
Now: 2018-02-03 18:02:26<br>
$start_datemostfinishedweekly: 2018-02-09 16:00:00<br>
$expiresmostfinishedweekly: 2018-02-16 16:00:00<br>
$start_dateplaytimeweekly: 2018-02-02 16:00:00<br>
$expireshetiplaytimeweekly: 2018-02-09 16:00:00<br>
```

Comment: @Joe did you check my answer? Have you solved your problem?